# Short Story: Physicist Discovers how to fuse a common element

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, nuclear-weapons

A lone Physicist discovers how to fuse a common element, probably Iron.
He is debating whether he should suppress the knowledge by not submitting a paper.

He reflects on his life and how 'Hell is other people' but has finally decided to suppress the knowledge.

Then some unruly youths break the window of his apartment and he changes his mind, he will submit the paper.

I read this sometime between the late 1960's and the late 1970's.
I believe it may have been written nearer to WWII amd may have been influenced by Edward Teller raising the possibility that the Trinity Explosion may ignite the atmosphere.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/173248/101407), this is likely "[Judgment Day](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55801)" (1955) by L. Sprague de Camp.

The scientist discovers how to cause a nuclear reaction *using* (but not consuming) the iron in the Earth's crust:

> My chain reaction uses *iron*, the last thing that would normally be employed in such a series. It's at the bottom of the atomic energy curve. Anything else can be made into iron with a release of energy, while it take energy to make iron into anything else.
>
> Really, the energy doesn't come from the iron, but from the... the other elements in the reaction. But the iron is necessary. It is not exactly a catalyst, as it is transmuted and then turned back to the iron again, whereas a true catalyst remains unchanged. But the effect is the same. With iron so common in the crust of the earth, it should be possible to blow the entire crust off with one big *poof*.

Most of the story is an introspective analysis of all his grudges with humanity and all of its bullies, and after suffering one more depredation by them, it ends with him deciding that he hates them all enough to see it ended.

> I was so buried in my problem that I forgot about Mischief Night, and as usual stopped in town for dinner at a restaurant before taking the train out to my suburb. When I got home, I found that in the hour of darkness before my arrival, the boys had given my place the full treatment. The soaped windows and the scattered garbage and the toilet paper spread around were bad but endurable. However, they had also burgled my garage and gone over my little British two-seater. The tires were punctured, the upholstery slashed, the paint scratched, and the wiring ripped out of the engine. There were other damages like uprooted shrubbery—
>
> To make sure I knew what they thought, they had lettered a lot of shirt-cardboards and left them around, reading: OLD LADY ORMONT IS A NUT! BEWARE THE MAD SCIENTIST!
>
> That decided me. There is one way I can be happy during my remaining years, and that is by the knowledge that all these bullies will get theirs some day. I hate them. I hate them. I hate everybody. I want to kill mankind. I'd kill them by slow torture if I could. If I can't, blowing up the earth will do. I shall write my report.

Comment: Just a query - the linked article refers to the scientist as 'he' but your quote refers to 'old lady Ormont'. Is the scientist a woman or is 'old lady Ormont' being used as an insult?

Comment: @Peter It's a juvenile insult.

Answer (score 12):

Judgement Day  by L. Sprague de Camp.

Full text can be read [here](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v55n06_1955-08_UnkSc-cape1736/Astounding_v55n06_1955-08_UnkSc-cape1736_djvu.txt).

Here's the ending.

> I had thought about the matter for several days without a decision. Then came Mischief Night. This is the night before Hallowe’en, when the local kids raise hell. The following night they go out again to beg candy and cookies from the people whose windows they have soaped and whose garbage-pails they have upset.
>
> All the boys in my neighborhood hate me. I don’t know why. It’s one of those things like a dog’s sensing the dislike of another dog. 'Though I don’t scream or snarl at them and chase them, they somehow know I hate them even when I have nothing to do with them.
>
> I was so buried in my problem that I forgot about Mischief Night, and as usual stopped in town for dinner at a restaurant before taking the train out to my suburb. When I got home, I found that in the hour of darkness before my arrival, the boys  had given my place the full treatment. The soaped windows and the scattered garbage and the toilet-paper spread around were bad but endurable. However, they had also burgled my garage and gone over my little British two-seater. ’The tires were punctured, the upholstery slashed, the paint scratched, and the wiring ripped out of the engine. There were other damages like uprooted shrubbery.
>
> To make sure I knew what they thought, they had lettered a lot of shirt-cardboards and left them around, reading: OLD LADY  ORMONT IS A NUT! BEWARE THE MAD SCIENTIST!
>
> That decided me. There is one way I can be happy during my remaining years, and that is by the knowledge that all these bullies will get theirs some day. I hate them. I hate them. I hate everybody. I want to kill mankind. I'd kill them by slow torture if I could. If I can’t, blowing up the earth will do. I shall write my report.

Edit - ninja'd